# How to work in web application with multiline strings more effectively through Dart SDK?

Tags: dart

I want to perform this operation simply, correct and efficient. Also I don't want manually split string to lines.

Here is what I wish (`something like this but it is not particularly critical`).

```dart
var string = someMultilneString;
var reader = new StringReader(string);
while(true) {
  var line = reader.readLine();
  if(line == null) {
    break;
  }
  // work with line
}
```

If this (`or similar to this`) is not possible then why?

P.S.
Also, please, don't offer answers worse than this example. Because this way is well-known but this is bad design is always to write your own implementation for support common input and output operations.

```dart
List<String> StringToLines(String text) {
  var source = text.replaceAll('\r\n', '\n');
  source = source.replaceAll('\r', '\n');
  var lines = source.split('\n');
  var lenght = lines.length;
  if(lenght > 0 && lines[lenght - 1].isEmpty) {
    lines.length--;
  }

  return lines;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to split the string into lines? It's much simpler if you do.

Comment: What could be faster than going through the bytes and checking when you hit a LF? Maybe if you know the content you could estimate the position and potentially skip some checks. If you want it simple, wrap it in a useful function and it will be easy at the call-site :)

Comment: @KaiSellgren I don't want write my own new class but I just want use existing implementation and cannot find it in Dart SDK. May be it missing?

Comment: Just to check - is the question you're asking something along the lines of "I've looked for StringReader in the Dart SDK, but it doesn't seem to exist - why?"  If you're looking for the answer to the "why is it missing" question, you probably want to make that clearer.

Comment: @ChrisBuckett: Corrected. But main question is "How to work in web application with multiline strings more effectively through Dart SDK?"

Comment: @mezoni - How big are your strings? Unless you're working with megabyte+ strings, this doesn't matter. And if you are working with huge strings, you shouldn't be storing the entire string into memory.

Comment: @tjameson - "huge strings, you shouldn't be storing the entire string into memory". Often good implementation is an lazy access (serial as read from file). Byte-per-byte. One big array of bytes better then array of strings. Next string created only on demand when invoked readLine. But I not found anything similar (professional) in Dart SDK. Maybe bad looking?

Comment: @mezoni - If you wanted a solution that worked with streams, you should have specified that in your question. Your question was about working with multiline strings in memory. If you wanted support for streams, you'd have to use an asynchronous API using Futures. Also, byte-per-byte is a terrible implementation. It should read bytes in chunks into a buffer to take advantage of OS-level buffers.

Answer (score 3):

Just split the string by line:

```
String str = someMultilineString;
str.split("\n").forEach((line) {
    // work with line
});
```

It's the most simple way of doing it, and it should be fast enough (unless your string is huge).  See [docs](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/String.html#split).

If you really want your idiom, you could make your own class:

```
class StringReader {
    String str;
    int i;
    int start = 0;
    StringReader(this.str);

    String readLine() {
        // we've exhausted the string
        if (this.start < 0) return null;

        String ret;
        this.i = this.str.indexOf("\n", this.start);
        if (this.i < 0) {
            // this is the last line
            ret = this.str.substring(this.start);
        } else {
            ret = this.str.substring(this.start, this.i);
        }
        // if this is the last line, start will be -1
        this.start = this.i;
        return ret;
    }
}

var reader = new StringReader(someMultilineString);
for (var str = reader.readLine(); str != null; str = reader.readLine()) {
    // do something with line
}
```

But the `split` version is much simpler and more idiomatic.

Comment: Sorry, but your way it not safest and not universal. It not used Dart SDK but proposed to spend time for writing extra class. All you offered I was known earlier. I want simply, correct and efficient.

Comment: @mezoni - The simple, correct and efficient way is the first. I provided the second to be API compatible with your proposed example, and I also don't think it makes sense. Why can't you just use `String.split`? That's what it was designed for.

Comment: No problem. Thanks! But my question not about algorithms. Question is as in title "How to work in web application with multiline strings more effectively through Dart SDK?"

Comment: @mezoni - And I gave you the answer: `String.split`. That's the simplest and most effective way to do it.

Comment: Here's an upvote for you for effort but not for the correct answer. Or may be problem is not you but Dart SDK?